# C++: Using cout causing change in value of a variable

Tags: c++

I was learning about how to use classes and wrote the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class DQNode
{
    public:
    int data;
    DQNode *next, *last;

    DQNode(int num, DQNode *n, DQNode *l)
    {
        data = num;
        next = n;
        last = l;
    }
};

class Deque
{
    private:
    DQNode *top, *bottom;
    int size;

    public:
    Deque()
    {
        top = NULL;
        bottom = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    void addFirst(int inp)
    {
        DQNode nn(inp, NULL, top);
        if(top != NULL)
        {
            (*top).next = &nn;
        }
        top = &nn;
        if(bottom == NULL)
        {
            bottom = &nn;
        }
    }

    void PrintAll()
    {
        cout<<top->data<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Deque n;
    n.addFirst(5);
    cout<<"yo"<<endl;
    n.PrintAll();
}
```

The above code prints "yo" followed by a random integer, interesting part is that on removing `cout<<"yo"<<endl;`the output is exactly as expected i.e 5.
So, if someone understands what is going wrong please help me.

Comment: `addFirst` makes `top` point to a local variable. The variable is destroyed when the function returns, leaving `top` a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use it afterwards exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behavior.

This is what happens when you break the rules. When you're lucky, you program crashes with a segmentation fault. Other times, you're unlucky and your program misbehave.

How did you break the rules? Well, you access a dead object.

The source of the problem is happening in your `addFirst` function. You store a `DQNode` in your `Deque` but that node dies.

You see, *all* local variable with automatic storage have well defined rules for when they live and die. Their lifetime is scope based. It look like this:

```
                                //      Lifetimes
void addFirst(int inp)          //   inp
{                               //    | 
    DQNode nn(inp, NULL, top);  //    |       nn
    if(top != NULL)             //    |       |
    {                           //    |       |
        (*top).next = &nn;      //    |       +--- <- top->next
    }                           //    |       |
    top = &nn;                  //    |       +--- <- top
    if(bottom == NULL)          //    |       |
    {                           //    |       |
        bottom = &nn;           //    |       +--- <- bottom
    }                           //    |       |
}                               //    |       X -- nn dies
                                //    X -- inp dies
```

Variable with automatic lifetimes are first to live, last to die. There is no exceptions. At the `}` character at the end of the function, where its scope ends, all local variable are destroyed. `nn` first, then `inp`.

At that point, `top`, `bottom` or `top->next` is still pointing to `nn`, which has been destroyed!

Then, in your `PrintAll` function is reading through the pointers=, which point to a destroyed variable. At that point, you read whatever is on the stack in that point of the program. A simple call to `cout` can allocate variables in the places where `nn` was, and assign whatever needed values. You pointer will still point there, and print garbage.

---

What can you do about it?

Well, you don't want automatic storage. It doesn't do what you want. You want to take control over the lifetime of the variables and deallocate them when you decide when you don't need them anymore. This is called the *free store*. You create objects there using *dynamic allocation*:

```
void addFirst(int inp)
{
    // new will dynamically allocate the object on the free store.
    DQNode* nn = new DQNode(inp, NULL, top);
    if(top != NULL)
    {
        (*top).next = nn;
    }
    top = nn;
    if(bottom == NULL)
    {
        bottom = nn;
    }
} // the `nn` pointer dies, but not the object it refers to!
```

However, your program will never deallocate the variable on its own, you must do it manually or you'll get a memory leak.

```
~Deque() {
    // traverse the tree
    // delete all node in the tree
}
```

Luckily, there is also a tool called a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) which will take care of deleting the allocated object when it dies.

The name *unique_ptr* comes from *unique owner*. The ownership of memory can be transferred, but there is always one and only one owner. When the owner dies, it deallocate the object from the free store:

```
// create a int equal to 1 on the free store using dynamic allocation
std::unique_ptr<int> int_a = std::make_unique<int>(1);
std::unique_ptr<int> int_b = nullptr;

// transfer ownership from int_a to int_b
int_b = std::move(int_a); 

// int_a is null
// int_b point to a int equal to 1

// This is disallowed, you cannot have two owner, so no copy
// int_a = int_b;

// can have an observing raw pointer:
int* int_c = int_b.get();

// transfer ownership back
int_a = std::move(int_b);

// at that point int_a is equal to int_c
// int_a is the owner, int_c simply point to the same int.
// int_b is null

// Set the last owner to null:
int_a = nullptr;

// the int has been destroyed because there is no owner left.
// int_a is null, int_b is null
// int_c is a dangling pointer, point to the dead object.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solved the issue. I remember doing something similar in C and used malloc to allocate the memory, and it worked fine. So is the "new" command similar to that? Also, can I use the "delete" command to unallocate the memory instead of what you mentioned?

Comment: Yes. New is a bit more advanced than malloc as it returns a pointer of the right type and it also construct the object. To delete you have to write `delete my_ptr`. However it is rare to actually do that in modern C++, I suggest you to try `std::unique_otr`, which will delete automatically.